# Exceptions - Throw and catch right away

Tags: java, exception

Does it make sense to throw an exception and directly catch it just to print error?

```
if(...){

} else {
   try{
      throw new Exception();
   } catch (Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

Comment: I suppose it depends on the circumstance. Be mindful that throwing exceptions is expensive, and if you're just printing out an error message to a user, a simple `System.err.println(...)` might suffice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to throw-and-catch, you can simply call:

```
new Exception().printStackTrace();
```

or even easier:

```
Thread.dumpStack();
```

You can also get the stack trace from the current thread as an array:

```
StackTraceElement[] trace = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
```

If you want to do something more detailed like inspect the stack at runtime (e.g. to get the calling method's name).

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be useful only if you explicitly want to send the Exception to a log file with a LOGGER (into the catch block), or register it in an especific way.

Comment: So doing e.printStackTrace() makes sense since this will put the trace in the log?

Comment: No, this will not put trace in the log, but you could modify your catch block with something like Logger.error("Error: ", e), in order to register that exception into your Logger file